# No refresh with core-drawer-panel

Tags: polymer

I have a little problem with Polymer.. but i have no idea for fix it...

when i go to my website:
http://toi-meme-tu-c.hol.es/polymer-tutorial-master/team/
and i click on the "i" for information (Case Scaroboy) ALL the drawer-panel refresh... how fix-it without javascript?

I have tried to include the drawer-panel into a php page but it's not an issue...

So I asked here, because im a begineer with Polymer...
thanks, Scaroboy

Answer (score 0):

It must use Javascript i think because no core element so far build to replace the content directly. To load new content inside the main panel you will need ajax request which you can use core-ajax element (on v0.5) or iron-ajax element (on v0.8) but you will need to write Javascript function to handle the ajax response.

Or you can create your own element wrap ajax element with replace content inside container that you can pass through attribute.

Comment: thanks! but i've got a question, did you see the latence with core drawer panel?

Comment: It's because the browser loading a new page not with ajax request.